# Toggle Navbar in Angular Controller. Wrong $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, navigation, angularjs-scope, navbar

I've created a little webapp for learning purposes.

You can find this app here: https://github.com/Yannic92/ShoppingList

I have a question to angular and its scopes. In the index.html (https://github.com/Yannic92/ShoppingList/blob/master/src/main/resources/public/index.html) i have a navbar. My first approach was to put this navbar into a separate HTML-file and use ng-include to include this, because i don't want to have that much code in my index.html.

**First approach**

My index.html looks like this:

```
<html ng-app="shopping">
<head lang="de">
    ...
    <title>Einkaufsliste</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="navigation">
    <navbar class="navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" ng-include="'navigation/navigation.html'"></navbar>
    <div class="content col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8" ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The navbar like it is currently inside the `<navbar>` element in my code on github was in `navigation/navigation.html`
To collapse the navbar when clicking on a link of the navbar i put this code snippet into the `navigation`-controller (https://github.com/Yannic92/ShoppingList/blob/master/src/main/resources/public/navigation/navigation.js):

```
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
        $scope.navCollapsed = true;
    })
```

The code itself worked but it doesn't had any effect on the navbar. It doesn't collapse.

After putting the navbar.html content into the index.html everything worked fine so i think that the problem has something to do with the scope of angulars controller.

Can someone give me a hint how it would be possible to put my navbar into navigation.html AND toggle the navbars collapsed status inside my controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. ng-include creates a new scope. And because i had `navCollapsed = !navCollapsed` in the template, angular created a new navCollapsed in this childscope. so changes in the navigation-Controller won't have any effect. I Solved the problem by calling a function `toggleNavCollapsed()`which is defined in navigation-Controller